# Using T4 to generate Poco classes, ignores the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, poco, t4, edmx

I'm using the Poco & DbContext T4 template in vs 2010 to generate the pocos for my data access, i've modified it to match some syntax required by my data access layer.

I've one problem that, the identity column (StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity) in the edmx file dosn't affect the T4 generating process, here is my code for it:

```
var identity = edmProperty.TypeUsage.Facets.Where(f => f.Name == "StoreGeneratedPattern").FirstOrDefault();
        if (identity != null && ((System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreGeneratedPattern)identity.Value) == System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity)
                    isIdentity = true;
```

this is always be `false` , is there a any reason for this?

Comment: Guys, is this is a known issue? or the syntax I used is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StoreGeneratedPattern` is not stored in facets but in `MetadataProperties` try something like this:

```
var identity = edmProperty.MetadataProperties
                          .Where(m => m.Name == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern")
                          .FirstOrDefault();

bool isIdentity = identity != null && identity.Value == System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity.ToString();
```

Comment: Thx. Interestingly enough even MS does not know about this fact, in its latest EF 6 in 2015

Answer (score 0):

Ladislav has indeed right.

(this post hopefully can spare time for someone who are trying to use `IsStoreGeneratedIdentity`, `IsStoreGeneratedComputed` and `StoreGeneratedPattern` regardless of T4.) It did cost me more than 2 hours to locate the problem and with narrowed googling keywords locate this post)

**Interestingly enough even MS does not know about this fact, in its latest EF 6 in 2015**, and  `EdmProperty` class exposes trivially not working properties. It also interesting how can these simple (not working) properties pass a unit test in the last 4 years? The question arises, how many places these not working properties are utilized inside and dependent utilities and cause issues?

Not working `IsStoreGeneratedIdentity`code from MS EF6 assembly:

```
public bool IsStoreGeneratedIdentity
{
  get
  {
    Facet facet;
    if (this.TypeUsage.Facets.TryGetValue("StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out facet))
      return (StoreGeneratedPattern) facet.Value == StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Not working `IsStoreGeneratedComputed`code from MS EF6 assembly:

```
public bool IsStoreGeneratedComputed
{
  get
  {
    Facet facet;
    if (this.TypeUsage.Facets.TryGetValue("StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out facet))
      return (StoreGeneratedPattern) facet.Value == StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed;
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property uses this underlying and not working code in MS EF6 assembly:

```
internal static StoreGeneratedPattern GetStoreGeneratedPattern(EdmMember member)
{
  Facet facet;
  if (member.TypeUsage.Facets.TryGetValue("StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out facet) && facet.Value != null)
    return (StoreGeneratedPattern) facet.Value;
  return StoreGeneratedPattern.None;
}
```

Code comes from:

```
// Type: System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmMember
// Assembly: EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// MVID: 9A9FD4AC-352D-4B91-95F8-2AF29ABDC792
// Assembly location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\EntityFramework.dll
```

**Finally I've ended with the following extension methods as a replacement of the not working original ones:**

```
public static class EdmMemberExtensions
{
    public static StoreGeneratedPattern StoreGeneratedPattern2(this EdmMember @this)
    {
        const string name = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern";
        var metaDataProperty = @this.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == name);

        if (metaDataProperty == null)
        {
            return StoreGeneratedPattern.None;
        }

            return (StoreGeneratedPattern) Enum.Parse(typeof (StoreGeneratedPattern), (string) metaDataProperty.Value);
    }

    public static bool IsStoreGeneratedIdentity2(EdmMember @this)
    {
        return StoreGeneratedPattern2(@this) == StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity;
    }

    public static bool IsStoreGeneratedComputed2(EdmMember @this)
    {
        return StoreGeneratedPattern2(@this) == StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed;
    }
}
```